# how to set the "LOADING..." label in line chart?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I want to set the "Loading...." instead of "No data" in line chart.
Now in my code it execute line chart every 5 second then it display the chart.but before 5 second or when it loads it shows "No data".I want only "Loading.."instead of "No data".
thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you at least tell which Chart Framework you are using? Add it to your question

Comment: i am using line chart visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [SimplePanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html) that you initially populate with a "Loading..." label. When your 5-second-timer fires, you call the SimplePanel's [setWidget()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html#setWidget%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29) method to replace the "Loading..." label with the chart.

The following might be of use:

```java
public class LoadingComposite extends Composite
{
  private SimplePanel content;

  public LoadingIndicatorComposite()
  {
    content = new SimplePanel();
    content.setWidget(new Label("Loading...") /* or a loading indicator image */);
    initWidget(content);
  }

  public void setContent(Widget w)
  {
    content.setWidget(w);
  }
}
```

This composite initially displays a "Loading..." label until you call `setContent()`, passing the content you want to show.